Typescript function type definition, pros/cons of different syntax options?
A coworker and I have been adding function props to type interfaces in our TypeScript React app (using TS 4.9, not 5 yet) and wondering which syntax is preferred; from what we can tell they behave the same way.
Example 1:
interface Props {
  setTarget(target: Item): void;
}

Example 2:
interface Props {
  setTarget: (target: Item) => void;
}

I personally prefer example 2 since it leaves the property name as a plain string and is easier to read for me at first glance; however I can't argue with the fact that the first example takes up several fewer characters, and conciseness is a virtue. Is there any functional difference? Is one or the other safer?

One functional difference between method syntax and function-valued property syntax is that method parameters are checked bivariantly which is unsafe, as shown in this playground link. As for which one to prefer, that seems like an opinion question to me. By what metric would someone judge "better" here? Could you [edit] to clarify?

Throw an exception and look at the stack trace—not sure what current behavior is.

As currently written, this doesn't seem to solicit an objective answer. Example 1 uses named call signature syntax for the methods while example 2 uses property declarations that are function types. In addition to what @jcalz wrote, modifiers behave differently as well (example).

@jcalz That was my point—for me if there’s a loss of info in the trace that’d be my litmus test, and I don’t know what the current behavior is for anon fn props vs fn props, or if it’s the same across JS/TS runtimes ‍♂️ So I’d throw an exception and see what the trace is like in context.

Another functional difference, in addition to the one mentioned by @jcalz, is that method syntax defines an implicit this: Props argument whereas the "arrow" function type has this: void. This means that e.g. the typescript-eslint unbound-method rule will complain about destructuring a method from an object.

@jcalz I have no idea how it may/may not affect a given impl’s transpilation process, which is why I’d throw an exception to sanity-check the environment is in and see if there’s a difference, especially if I’m writing code that targets both Node and Bun, since iirc Bun uses its own transpiler. If you know what happens, awesome, that’s rad. I don’t, and if someone is asking what the differences are, that’s one thing I’d check. Doesn’t mean you have to ‍♂️ Type erasure has been a bane of existence since Java generics—I am familiar.

Okay, so if you're familiar with how Java generics are erased, if you asked "what's the difference between Array<Foo> and Array<Bar>?" and I said "throw an exception and look at the stack trace", you'd say "but wait, Foo and Bar are generic type arguments and get completely erased. Java runtime knows nothing about them. The stack trace would give you no information whatsoever." That's what I'm telling you about the entire TS type system. It is erased. It's not reified.

These are helpful comments, thank you. Edited to clarify I was mainly wondering if one or the other is safer, and it seems like function-valued properties are the way to go in this case. Does that seem correct?

Yes, function-valued properties are more type safe than methods, due to bivariance. Shall I write an answer to that effect?

Sorry for the delay, yes @jcalz that'd probably be helpful for future finders of this question/thread to see a clear answer. Thank you.
